# Is there a 2-connected k-regular graph without Hamiltonian path?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

In [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019013002214) (Construction 2.6 p860) the authors have built examples of 
connected $k$-regular graph without Hamiltonian path, but with a cut-vertex (i.e. it is not $2$-connected).

*Question:* Is there a $2$-connected $k$-regular graph without Hamiltonian path?

*Remark*: every $2$-connected $k$-regular graph with at most $3k+3$ vertices admits a Hamiltonian cycle or is one of the two exceptions, which admit a Hamiltonian path.

Comment: Did you want a counterexample for *some* $k$? or a counterexample for *each* $k$?

Comment: The ArXiv version of the cited paper is at http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.6457.pdf

Comment: There is some discussion of $k=3$ at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4190/cubic-graphs-and-hamiltonian-paths

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take $k>3$ long paths between two vertices $a,b$. This graph is already 2-connected. Now add some edges to make it $k$-regular so that every edge joins only interior vertices of the same path (it is not hard). Then $G\setminus\{a,b\}$ has more connected components than any graph having Hamiltonian path with two vertices removed.

Comment: 1) The question is about paths, not cycles. 2) Start at $a$, take one of the paths to $b$, take the other path back to $a$ – isn't that a Hamiltonian cycle?

Comment: 2) I think, no, because we have $k>3$ paths between $a,b$. Well, for $k=3$ this does not work, but there exist another constructions.

Comment: OK. For $k=4$, your construction can give a graph on just 14 vertices. Very good.

Comment: I doubt, we need more vertices in paths for making graph $k$-regular. 22 vertices are enough for $k=4$.

Comment: Do you expect that $22$ is the smallest order for a $2$-connected $k$-regular non-traceable graph?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux no, I doubt that it is minimal

Answer (score 8):

According to [this excerpt](https://books.google.com/books?id=oIy9BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=%22non-traceable%20snark%22&source=bl&ots=5TwfjXw2q-&sig=vP7o1t9_XQmczQvNSOwAVlqQCus&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUq7-Iy7zNAhVD5WMKHejMD0EQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22non-traceable%20snark%22&f=false) from the book *[Covering Walks in Graphs](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4939-0305-4)* by Fujie & Zhang (2014), the [Zamfirescu graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZamfirescuGraphs.html) of order 36<sup>[1]</sup> is non-traceable (i.e.: does not contain a Hamiltonian path). Moreover, this graph is a [snark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_(graph_theory)) and hence 3-regular and 2-connected.

The [Thomassen graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ThomassenGraphs.html) of order 34<sup>[2]</sup> is also 3-regular, 2-connected, and non-traceable.

1. Zamfirescu, Tudor. "[On longest paths and circuits in graphs.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/24490747)" Mathematica Scandinavica 38.2 (1976): 211-239.
2. Thomassen, Carsten. "[Hypohamiltonian and hypotraceable graphs.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X74900740)" Discrete Mathematics 9.1 (1974): 91-96.

Answer (score 6):

The smallest graph coming from the construction of Fedor Petrov's answer can be realized as follows:

[image]